# helm upgrade mongodb fails with error "unable to build kubernetes objects"

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

In process of project initialization I have a command:

```
helm upgrade mongodb mongodb/mongodb --install --set replicaSet.enabled=true.
```

Which fails with error:

```
Release "mongodb" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: [resource mapping not found for name: "mongodb-arbiter" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first, resource mapping not found for name: "mongodb-secondary" namespace: "" from "": no matches for kind "PodDisruptionBudget" in version "policy/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first]
```

Can you please suggest what to do?

Comment: which version of kubernetes are you using?
`kubectl --version`
I think you are probably on an old version of it.

Answer (score 1):

The version of Kubernetes you are using is too new for your helm charts.
Within the latest version of Kubernetes PodDisruptionBudget lives in `policy/v1` and not `policy/v1beta1` where your chart is looking for it.